# Job scheduling tool with master-slave architecture

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, master-slave

I am looking for a tool which will execute a job when a user submits it through UI/CLI.
The execution can happen in the slave nodes also.If all the slave nodes are busy, the master should automatically deploy the slave node and execute the job.
I have already tried my hands on Jenkins,Hudson,Puppet,Chef,Quartz. But either of them lack what I'm looking for.

Is there any open source tool which could fulfill by requirements?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your requirements? I know Jenkins supports what you have listed - where did it came short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list you provided did not meet your requirements ans expectations then it's time to go a bit more flexible , configurable and open system

Try out zookeeper a must have scheduling ,synchronisation and maintain acne tool for distributed systems 
http://zookeeper.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are only running a handful of processes/jobs, there is a free Community Edition to [JAMS Job Scheduler.](http://www.jamsscheduler.com/DownloadCommEdition.aspx)